# Coercing a Radeon 4650 HD to Work with Ubuntu 8.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card

Is it possible to get Ubuntu 8.04 truly recognize my Radeon 4650 HD?  I'd like to take advantage of the 3D hardware acceleration and the dual monitor abilities of it, but I can't get the ATI drivers working.  I've tried the standard ones, the radeonhd ones, the proprietary ones from ATI.  I've followed a half dozen howtos, and looked at the UbuntuLinux.org forums - on which there is a thread suggesting that the linux drivers for the newer HD cards are still buggy and non-functional.

So my question: Has anyone gotten a Radeon 4000+ HD working with Ubuntu 8.04 LTS.  Where, by working I mean, full dual display, HD and 3D support?  How'd you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - but it's a bit of black magic and blind luck.

I got my 4870 working in 8.04, but I had to build the drivers manually and hand-edit my xorg.conf.

Best bet is to make the leap to 9.04 - the card will work well there out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, going to 9.04 did it.  Guess it's an LTS fail, but oh well.  I've forgotten why I stayed with LTS in the first place - so that works for me :)